# Python: Exp of complex number is not working

Tags: python, numpy

I am really new to Python and usually code with MATLAB, so I tried to creat this small code that has exp(complex number) in a for loop. (I need the for loop since I have multidimensional matrix along the code).

Every time I add the term (1j*) the code wont work and it show the following error

```
    TypeError: can't convert complex to float

    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
                   , line 17, in <module>
        Zx[n,m] =np.exp(1j*np.pi*(m)*np.sin(theta[:,n])*np.sin(phi[:,n]))
    
    ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

and here is the code

```
import numpy as np 
M=4
N=5
Zx = np.zeros([N,M])
theta = np.pi*np.random.rand(1,N)
phi = 2*np.pi*np.random.rand(1,N)
for n in range(N):
    for m in range(M):
        Zx[n,m] =np.exp(1j*np.pi*(m)*np.sin(theta[:,n])*np.sin(phi[:,n]))
```

What could be the reason?
Thanks

Comment: use `[0,n]` instead of `[:,n]`, or simply use `rand(N)` instad of `rand(1,N)` and then just `[n]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `np.zeros` creates an array of type `np.float64`.  If you try to assign a complex value to an element of such an array, you'll get the error `TypeError: can't convert complex to float`.

Your code works if you make `Zx` an array of complex numbers:

```
Zx = np.zeros([N, M], dtype=complex)
```

---

FYI: You can use *broadcasting* to eliminate the Python for-loops in your code:

```
M = 4
N = 5

theta = np.pi*np.random.rand(1, N)
phi = 2*np.pi*np.random.rand(1, N)
m = np.arange(M)
Zx = np.exp(1j*np.pi*m*np.sin(theta.T)*np.sin(phi.T))
```